# Problem Socket.IO with custom path or namespace

Tags: node.js, socket.io

after authorization, the user is redirected to the address http://localhost:3000/home where there is chat, but when the link http://localhost:3000/home opens, I get an error [error](http://i.piccy.info/i9/e3459380f0ff62568724702cd8373776/1580431049/61224/1359479/1.png) in the picture you can see the error

code app.js

```
   app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'views')));
app.set("view engine", "hbs");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use("/", userRouter);
app.use("/signup", signupRouter);

var server = require('http').createServer(app);

var io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.path('/home');

var controller = require('./controllers/chatController.js');
io.on('connection', controller.respond );
```

router

```
  const express = require("express");
  const userRouter = express.Router();
  var homeController = require('../controllers/homeController.js');
  userRouter.get("/home", homeController.home);
```

homeController.js

```
let user=require("../models/user.js");

exports.home = function(request, response) {
  let data=[request.session.username, request.session.username];
  if (request.session.loggedin) {
    user.getUser(data).then(function(item){

      response.render("index.hbs", {user:item[0]});
    });
  } else {
    response.send('Please login to view this page!');
  }

};
```

i use the handlebars, and socket.io 2.3.0

I understand that this is the problem with the paths or not?
how to solve it?

Comment: What are you hoping to accomplish by using a custom socket.io path?  If you do configure a custom socket.io path, you have to: 1) Make it different and unique from any page URLs you will use and 2) Configure the same path in server and client-side socket.io and 3) Adjust the path that you load the client library from in your web pages.

Comment: Put another way, do NOT use the same path for socket.io that you are using for web pages.  So, using this `userRouter.get("/home", homeController.home);`  and `io.path('/home');` is going to cause you problems.  The socket.io path should be invisible to the user and should be unique from anything used in your other URLs.  There is normally NO reason to modify it at all.  What the socket.io library does is install a listener for whatever path it is using and use that path for it's own purposes.

Comment: Just remove all your custom socket.io paths and everything should be fine.

Comment: thank, I removed my custom paths, but I had errors. After, I found error in file app.

Comment: does that mean it connected fine and then you ran into some other, but unrelated error?